# How to pass the generated Buffered image from Servlet to the response?

Tags: java, servlets, web, httpresponse, bufferedimage

In my Servlet I generate a BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage bgImage = createImage();
```

and I save it:

```
saveImage(bgImg, getImageSaveDir() + IMAGE_NAME);
```

After that I want to return it to the response to show in a browser.

I tried to send the image to the response:

```
File imageFile = new File(getImageSaveDir() + IMAGE_NAME);
response.setContentType("image/png");
BufferedImage bufferedImg = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "png", out);
out.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I receive an Exception:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:296)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:98)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.close(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:238)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1580)
    at tv.clever.xml.TeamImageProcessor.process(TeamImageProcessor.java:157)
    at tv.clever.api.ApiServlet.doProcessing(ApiServlet.java:458)
    at tv.clever.api.ApiServlet.process(ApiServlet.java:219)
    at tv.clever.api.ApiServlet.doPost(ApiServlet.java:98)
    at tv.clever.api.ApiServlet.doGet(ApiServlet.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at tv.clever.utils.messageresource.UTF8EncodingFilter.doFilter(UTF8EncodingFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at tv.clever.utils.security.URLFilter.doFilter(URLFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at tv.clever.utils.security.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:761)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:785)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:598)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
    ... 39 more
```

> What is the best way to pass the generated Buffered image from Servlet to the response and display it in the browser?

I've tried this:

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(getImageSaveDir() + IMAGE_NAME));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
response.setContentType("image/png");
response.setContentLength(imageInByte.length);
ServletOutputStream servletoutputstream = response.getOutputStream();
servletoutputstream.write(imageInByte);
servletoutputstream.flush();
```

Now the Exception does not appear, but the code still doesn't work:(

Comment: Just a guess, but try adding `response.setContentType("image/png");` at start of your response.

Comment: Thank you for your response but `response.setContentType("image/png")`  doesn't helped me.

Comment: Can you try something like http://pastebin.com/TryAjs7E (you will just need to replace my fixed data with yours).

Comment: @Pshemo Can we execute it, I mean does it provided a web server support behind the scene for execution? Sorry, I didn't got it, what's the use of it?

Comment: It is code I placed in my `doGet` method in my servlet (I assume your question was about code in servlet). Anyway if your request is POST you can place this code in `doPost` method.

Comment: @Pshemo Ok, thanks, got it. I thought this is some utility to emulate web server transactions online.

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: 1: Don't use `ImageIO` to read/write the image. Just stream the bytes directly from disk (the `imageFile` file), using `FileInputInstream` and copy the bytes to `out`. Alternatively, don't use a file at all, and save the image directly to the servlet `OutputStream`.
2: Don't `close()` `out` after you are done writing. I think the servlet container should take care of that for you.

Comment: @Pshemo - ImageIO.write() doesn't work for me

Comment: @Dylan I would say try other approaches - https://www.google.ca/search?q=setContentType&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=RBydVZLxNsLp-QHivoP4Bg#q=servlet+send+image+in+response. One you should definitely try is reading or converting image in array of bytes and then directly committing it to client using `ServletOutputStream#write()`

Comment: @Dylan Did you try other approaches? Have got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code of `org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes` which is where the exception is coming.

```
    // If we really have something to write
    if (cnt > 0) {
        // real write to the adapter
        outputChunk.setBytes(buf, off, cnt);
        try {
            coyoteResponse.doWrite(outputChunk);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An IOException on a write is almost always due to
            // the remote client aborting the request. Wrap this
            // so that it can be handled better by the error dispatcher.
            throw new ClientAbortException(e);
        }
    }
```

Now notice the comment in the exception which says

> An IOException on a write is almost always due to the remote client
>   aborting the request.

To me, it looks like some connection problem between your browser and server. Probably the connection is broken.

Now there could be multiple reasons for HTTP connection getting disconnected, like:

- Request was taking too long to respond, so the web server timed out the request, as per the HTTP timeout.
- Request was terminated from client.
- You sent something which was not understood by client or non-acceptable MIME type, so while web server was trying to commit the response, there was error.

In case of Weblogic, if I initiate a server transaction from browser, and then close the browser before server could respond, then while commiting the response, WL will throw below exception.
In your case as well root exception is `IOException` but it is wrapped to `ClientAbortException` to be meaningful on log console.

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
```

So, you may want to:

- Debug from the connection perspective. Probably have [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for debugging HTTP traffic.
- Verify that server is not taking too long, so web server is getting HTTP timed out. If so, increase the web server HTTP timeout limit.
- Verify image type is "png".
- Try different ways to send image to UI - https://www.google.ca/search?q=setContentType&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=RBydVZLxNsLp-QHivoP4Bg#q=servlet+send+image+in+response

  - One you should definitely try is reading or converting image in array of bytes and then directly committing it to client using `ServletOutputStream#write()`